# Using Groovy(or Java) how can I convert a org.joda.time.LocalDateTime to a java.util.date?

Tags: java, datetime, groovy, jodatime

Using Groovy (or Java) how can I convert a `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` to a `java.util.Date`?

```
import org.joda.time.*

Calendar cal = Calendar.instance
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

Date startOfTheMonth = cal.time 

LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime()
    localDateTime = localDateTime.withDayOfMonth(1)
    localDateTime = localDateTime.withTime(0,0,0,0)
    localDateTime.minusMonths(6)

Date dateFromLocalDate = localDateTime.toDateTime().toDate()

println startOfTheMonth
println dateFromLocalDate

assert  startOfTheMonth.equals(dateFromLocalDate)
```

using `localDateTime.toDateTime().toDate()` gives me a `java.util.Date` that is 6 hours off I'm in Central Standard time (GMT +6)

How do I convert my `LocalDateTime` date back to a `java.util.Date` such that the time matches?

Comment: Just to qualify this example I'm using Groovy Version: 1.6.7 JVM: 1.6.0_16 on Linux with Joda-time 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

The problem is the use of [Calendar.HOUR](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) which indicates the hour of the morning or afternoon.

Either use:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
```

or:

```
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM)
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)
```

Comment: I wasn't clear with my example, I have updated what I meant as well as used equals() for the sake of clarity.  (Groovy handles date equality using '==' [which utilizes equals()] and 'is' for identity)

Comment: ??  I think Chandra is right, as your example exists now the "startOfTheMonth" = "Fri Jan 01 12:00:00 CST 2010" and dateFromLocalDate is "Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2010", they're off by 12 hours, not 6 hours that you'd get for CST offset from GMT.  If you switch to HOUR_OF_DAY instead of HOUR, the assertion works.

Comment: I'm getting different results:  startOfTheMonth = "Jan 01 12:00:00 CST 2010" and dateFromLocalDate = "dateFromLocalDate" Does the Example assertion work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere during the conversion, the wrong time zone is being used. Debug this by seeing what the default time zone is `TimeZone.getDefault()` and what the Joda-Time default is `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`.

You can be more explicit when doing the conversion too:

`localDateTime.toDateTime(yourDesiredZone).toDate()`