# Convert java.util.date into java.time.localdate type?

Tags: java, java-8

How to convert java util date into java.time LocalDate type.java.time is int the JDK 1.8 version.

Comment: Java doesn't do date conversions unless you write some code.  Voice to code facility is yet to be implemented.

Comment: I'm asking how to convert the date.If i know the method,i won't ask this question here

Comment: Unless you make even a feeble attempt, chances are that you wouldn't get to know it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date inputDate = new Date();
LocalDate date = inputDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

I found this duplicated post after answer:
[Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate)

Comment: please. I want to convert localdate into date type.Because i want to set the date into jdate chooser

Comment: Are there any datechoosers supports java localdate?

Comment: From localdate to date?

Comment: yeah. i want to convert from local date to date type

Comment: I hope this help you!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597671/how-to-convert-joda-localdate-to-java-util-date

Comment: No.Its not Joda localdate.This local date contain in the java.time library.Those methods not works

Comment: Ahhmm!! OK. This one?? Joda localdate to java.util.date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597671/how-to-convert-joda-localdate-to-java-util-date

Comment: No.Its not joda time.Its java.time.LocalDate;.Comes with JDK8.Joda Library methods not works :(

Comment: Check that codes and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009795/using-groovyor-java-how-can-i-convert-a-org-joda-time-localdatetime-to-a-java

Comment: The user should change the project source binary format in project properties to JDK 8